# Break with For loop in Java doesn't make the loop stop

Tags: java, excel, loops, selenium

I have the following code

```
    File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Excel Files\\XLFile.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    // Start
    String chromePath = "C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // UAT
    driver.get("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html");
    //Building Action Interaction
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    if (sh1.getRow(0) !=null && sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1) !=null) { 
    List<WebElement> allopts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']//option"));

    List<String> xlall= new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<Row> ixlrows = sh1.rowIterator();

    while (ixlrows.hasNext())
    {
        Row row= ixlrows.next();

        if (row.getRowNum() > 0 && row.getCell(1) != null)
        {
            xlall.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

    for (WebElement we : allopts)
    {
        if (xlall.contains(we.getText()))
        {
            act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .click(we)
                    .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .build()
                    .perform();
        }
    }
 }   
    wb.close();
    fis.close();
```

What I am doing is by matching the values coming from Excel and matching them with the application options it will select them one by one.

This is just an example code, the actual code has 1003 options that this loop has to go through. I want to get out of the loop as soon as it finds the values from excel, matches them with app options and clicks on them.

As you could see I have the tried placing the break inside the if statement and tried right after the if statement. But none works it still keeps on looping through all the options.

Where do i add the break to do that?

P.S. Everything else is working except the loop being broken after actions are completed.

P.S 2. this is part of Selenium WebDriver code using Java.

Update 1: Code Updated

Update 2: Does anyone think this break in this code has nothing to do with the for loop itself, its storing all the options from the app within array List allopts = ....? so it keeps on going even though there's a break? In that case what should i do to stop the array to capture all the options as soon as it seen the options and selects it?

**UPDATE 3:** there were another if statement. The code has been updated with parent if statement.

**EDIT: Finally with the help of @DonLeopardo it worked like magic,**

Here is the working code:

```
    if (sh1.getRow(0) !=null && sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1) !=null) { 
    List<WebElement> allopts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']//option"));

    List<String> xlall= new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<Row> ixlrows = sh1.rowIterator();

    while (ixlrows.hasNext())
    {
        Row row= ixlrows.next();

        if (row.getRowNum() > 0 && row.getCell(1) != null)
        {
            xlall.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(xlall) 

WebElement we;
for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++)
{
    we=(WebElement)allopts.get(i);
    if (copy.contains(we.getText()))
    {
        act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(we)
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                .build()
                .perform();
        copy.remove(copy.indexOf(we.getText()));
    }
    if(copy.size()<1)
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit the source code and format it so we can get what you are posting there...

Comment: Are you sure that it actually enters the if?

Comment: If you uncomment the second `break`, the `for` loop will only process the first element in the `allopts` list, whether the `if` statement fires or not, which makes the following statement impossible: *"it still keeps on looping through all the options"*

Comment: Not enough code to see the problem. Is the if condition ever true? Is allopts maybe empty? Use debugger or debug prints. Try autoformatting the source code (Java IDE's generally have "format" feature) to spot structure problems.

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa Code updated

Comment: @DonLeopardo Yes it does the code is working absolutely fine but with the real test where I have 1003 selections this code doesnt break the loop after it finds and selected the element(s)

Comment: @hyde code updated, thanks

Comment: @Andreas Please take a look at the code now there were another parent if statement. Sorry about that & thanks a lot

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa Please take a look at the code now there were another parent if statement. Sorry about that & thanks a lot

Comment: @hyde Please take a look at the code now there were another parent if statement. Sorry about that & thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this options, but i don't know if they are going to work because the initial code should work.
Option 1:

```
boolean flag=true;
int i=0;
while(i<allopts && flag)
{
if(conditons)//Put your conditions
{
//code
flag=false;
}
i++;
}
```

Option 2:

```
boolean flag=false;
for (WebElement we:allopts)
{
if (condition)//Put your conditions
{
//code
flag=true;
}
if(flag)
{
break;
}
}
```

**EDIT:**
Option 3: (this should work)

```
WebElement we;
for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++)
{
we=(WebElement)allopts.get(i);
if (condition)//Put your conditions using we like always: xlall.contains(we.getText())
    {
    //code
    break;
    }
}
```

I read that you can't stop a foreach or something like that.

**EDIT 2:** I think that now i understand the problem correctly.
You should do this:

```
List<String> allStrOpts=new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement we : allopts)
{
     allStrOpts.add(we.getText());
}
for(int i=0;i<xlall.size();i++)
{
     if(allStrOpts.contains(xlall.get(i))
     {
           act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(allopts.get(allStrOpts.indexOf(xlall.get(i))))
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                .build()
                .perform();
     }
}
```

If this demands a lot of time, you can try this one:

```
//List<String> copy=xlall.clone();

//or

List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(xlall) 

WebElement we;
for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++)
{
    we=(WebElement)allopts.get(i);
    if (copy.contains(we.getText()))
    {
        act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(we)
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                .build()
                .perform();
        copy.remove(copy.indexOf(we.getText()));
    }
    if(copy.size()<1)
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

I don't know which one has a better perfomance, i think that the second one, but i'm not sure. The order that i use to write them is the order in that they come to my mind.

Comment: Do you think this break in the initial code that i added has nothing to do with the for loop itself, its storing all the options from the app within array List<WebElement> allopts = ....? so it keeps on going even though there's a break?

Comment: In that case what should i do to stop the array to capture all the options as soon as it seen the options and selects it?

Comment: In my second option, if you replace the flag=true; with a break; should work, but you said that it dosn't work and i don't know why, but i give to you other options that should work, i don't know if they are going to work, maybe the problem is another.

Comment: There is another if before all of these let me add that.

Comment: I read some documentation, and i'm going to add a third option that i think it's the correct one.

Comment: The parent if added, thanks a lot

Comment: If it's not solved you should try my option 3, i think that it should work (i realy want to know if that works, i'm pretty shure that it should)

Comment: I added the code as follow - `for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++) { if (WebElement we:allopt.get(i) { //code } }` its not working the if statement doesnt take the WebElement

Comment: There are some errors in your copypaste, this is the correct way: `for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++) { if (xlall.contains(((WebElement)allopts.get(i)).getText())) { //code } }`

Comment: within the if thats what i have as action - `act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .click(we)
                    .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .build()
                    .perform();` as you could see the click is referring to the single webelement as 'we' how do i implement that with this code please?

Comment: ((WebElement)allopts.get(i)) that is we. You can do this too: `WebElement we; for(int i=0;i<allopts.size();i++) {  we=((WebElement)allopts.get(i));` and then use we. I'm going to edit the answer for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does get out of the loop but it only selects the first option coming from excel it doesn't go on selecting the second option after the first one since there are more than one value to be selected

Comment: And you want to read all the options? If you want that, why do you want a break? You have more than one if in the loop and you want to skip all the other ifs if it enter in one? Sorry, but i think that i not understand the problem correctly ;(

Comment: Lets say the app has 100 options and xl has 2 options that we need to select from those 100 options, what i am trying to do is loop through all xl options and match the value from the app (while looping the app) and select only those 2 options and as soon as they are selected stop looping on the app

Comment: allopts have all the options and xlall contains the selected ones? If that's the case, i know how to solve it, if it's not, tell me what are them and where is each thing.

Comment: yes, so the code is taking from xlall as long as there are values it will keep on clicking on those options from allopts and once its done it should exit out of the loop, btw thanks so much for everything

Comment: If xlall contains all the selected options, you do it backwards, you should loop in xlall instead of loop in allopts. I'm going to edit my answer to clarify that. And no problem, i'm here to help.

Comment: If you would please. :)

Comment: Ready, i edit the answer.

Comment: And if you aren't going to use xlall again, you can use it instead of copy (for the second solution in the second edit)

Comment: thanks, trying it out but where did clone in `List<String> copy=xlall.clone();` came from, i m kinda not clear about that

Comment: Never mind i got it, you are trying to close the original xl array but it doesn't let me do that

Comment: That's because i'm going to delete items of the list, and if you use xlall, you aren't going to have it later on. Then i do a copy of it to delete from there. If you don't want to use xlall later, or you are going to reload it after use it again, you can not use copy and instead, replase all aparitions of it for xlall.

Comment: trying with this one List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(xlall)

Comment: I was just about say that :P

Comment: amazing & magic happens again :), thanks very much wholeheartedly -  it's working like magic.  Truly thanks again.

Comment: if you don't mind i will update your response with this `List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(xlall) `

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it worked. Yes, edit the answer with your working code, and select it like the correct answer. If you can, put the working code in your question too under the "EDIT: Working code".

Comment: the second option from edit 2 worked btw, updated. :)

Comment: Should i delete all the other options or let it like it is?

Comment: I think let it be there, never know who might need other options. :)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class you can use to choose the options

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.name("toppings")); // find the <select> tag
Select select = new Select(selectElement); // initialize Select instance

for (WebElement we : allopts) {
    if (xlall.contains(we.getText())) {
        select.selectByVisibleText(we.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way with my actual application, the way the code was written is working absolutely fine except  the code doesn't break the loop after it finds and selected the element(s)

Comment: Please take a look at the code now there were another parent if statement. Sorry about that & thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the code you presented, you would place the break inside the `if` statement.  In the event that the `if`'s test evaluates to `true`, and none of the methods earlier in the `if` block throws an exception, the `break` will break out of the nearest enclosing loop (or `switch`).  Of course, an exception would also cause execution to leave the loop in your example code.

Inasmuch as you seem to indicate that you have already tried putting a `break` there, I'm inclined to think that the code you have presented does not adequately capture the problem.  That might be because there is another level of looping that is not escaped, because the `break` you tried to insert was inside a `switch` statement, or because the `break` is bypassed by throwing an exception that is caught later within the loop.

Comment: The code updated, thanks a lot

Comment: @Ami, nothing you changed in your update alters my analysis.  If you want to break out of the `for` loop after identifying and processing an option, then you would do so by putting a `break` statement inside the `if` block, after the processing.

Comment: Do you think this break in the code has nothing to do with the for loop itself, its storing all the options from the app within array List allopts = ....? so it keeps on going even though there's a break? In that case what should i do to stop the array to capture all the options as soon as it seen the options and selects it?

Comment: When execution reaches an unlabelled `break` statement, it branches from there to the next statement after the end of the nearest enclosing loop (`for`, `while`, or `do ... while`) or `switch`.  Period.  If you place a `break` at the end of the `if` block in the code you presented but observe the loop running until it exhausts the contents of `allopts` then it follows that the break is never reached.

Comment: Is it possible that the classes you are testing do not correspond to the code you are presenting?  For example, did you perhaps forget to recompile and/or re-deploy after adding the `break`?

Comment: Please take a look at the code now there were another parent if statement. Sorry about that & thanks a lot

Comment: Your additional `if` statement still makes no difference to the analysis.  Only an additional level of loop nesting or a `switch` statement you forgot to mention could do.